# Recursive procedural macros, looping through tokens, and looping through characters

Tags: rust, macros

I wrote a program in Scheme a while ago that would evolve an L-system using macros. Essentially there are rules about how tokens are expanded which would be run recursively. For example, given the rules:

```
F => F F
X => X < F > F
> => identity (stay >)
< => identity (stay <)
```

If we start with `X`, we get:

```
// after 0 iterations
X

// after 1 iteration
X < F > F

// after 2 iterations
X < F > F < F F > F F

// after 3 iterations
X < F > F < F F > F F < F F F F > F F F F
```

*et cetera*. In Scheme this was a charm to do. Super simple matching and recursive macro definitions. The call looked something like this:

```lisp
; macro name    iters  starting tokens
(evolve-lsys-n  5      X F X)
```

But I'm really struggling to do this with Rust.

Standard `macro_rules!` have the advantage of pattern matching, which is really nice. But unfortunately there's no unquoting/quasiquoting as far as I can tell, so I can't actually tail recurse (I think?)

Procedural macros seem like the way to go, but I'm also struggling with how to do this.

If the input is the same as what I had in Scheme (`evolve!(X F X)`), how do I go about actually looping through these tokens?

With rust being more powerful, I'm also hoping I can have a more expressive input without additional spaces. For example, `evolve!(XFX)` would be nice. Is this possible? This doesn't seem like much of a benefit here, but when defining the expansion rules they can actually get pretty big so it would be nice to avoid spaces.

Finally, in Scheme I was also able to implement parametric macros. This means that some "tokens" would have parameters. A call would look something like this: `evolve!(X F(10) X)`, and the expansion for `F(10)` would take the parameter and do something with it, for example `F(t) F(t * 2)`, so that `F(10)` would expand to `F(10) F(20)`.

Obviously I can do all of this without macros. I really like the idea of using macros for all of this though, as it's just an interesting exercise and comes from the idea of "defining your own grammar" which is the most attractive part of Scheme and lisp-like languages to me.

Thanks,